# Pyspark : Pass dynamic Column in UDF

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Trying to send list of column one by one in UDF using for loop but getting error i.e Data frame not find col_name. currently in list list_col we have two column but it can be change .So i want to write a code which work for every list of column.In this code i am concatenating one row of column at a time and row value is in struct format i.e list inside a list . For every null i have to give space .

```
    list_col=['pcxreport','crosslinediscount']
    def struct_generater12(row):
    list3 = []
    main_str = ''
    if(row is None):
        list3.append(' ')
    else:
        for i in row:
            temp = ''
            if(i is None):
                temp+= ' '
            else:
                for j in i:
                    if (j is None):
                        temp+= ' '
                    else:
                        temp+= str(j)
            list3.append(temp)
    for k in list3:
        main_str +=k
    return main_str


    A = udf(struct_generater12,returnType=StringType())
    # z = addlinterestdetail_FDF1.withColumn("Concated_pcxreport",A(addlinterestdetail_FDF1.pcxreport))
    for i in range(0,len(list_col)-1):
        struct_col='Concate_'
        struct_col+=list_col[i]
        col_name=list_col[i]
        z = addlinterestdetail_FDF1.withColumn(struct_col,A(addlinterestdetail_FDF1.col_name))
        struct_col=''

    z.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addlinterestdetail_FDF1.col_name` implies the column is named `"col_name"`, you're not accessing the string contained in variable `col_name`.

When calling a `UDF` on a column, you can

- use its string name directly: `A(col_name)`
- or use pyspark sql function `col`:

  ```
  import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
  z = addlinterestdetail_FDF1.withColumn(struct_col,A(psf.col(col_name)))
  ```

You should consider using pyspark sql functions for concatenation instead of writing a UDF. First let's create a sample dataframe with nested structures:

```
import json
j = {'pcxreport':{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}, 'crosslinediscount':{'c': 'c', 'd': None, 'e': 'e'}}
jsonRDD = sc.parallelize([json.dumps(j)])
df = spark.read.json(jsonRDD)
df.printSchema()
df.show()

    root
     |-- crosslinediscount: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- e: string (nullable = true)
     |-- pcxreport: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
     |    |-- b: string (nullable = true)

    +-----------------+---------+
    |crosslinediscount|pcxreport|
    +-----------------+---------+
    |       [c,null,e]|    [a,b]|
    +-----------------+---------+
```

We'll write a dictionary with nested column names:

```
list_col=['pcxreport','crosslinediscount']
list_subcols = dict()
for c in list_col:
    list_subcols[c] = df.select(c+'.*').columns
```

Now we can "flatten" the `StructType`, replace `None` with `' '`, and concatenate:

```
import itertools
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.select([c + '.*' for c in list_col])\
    .na.fill({c:' ' for c in list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_subcols.values()))})\
    .select([psf.concat(*sc).alias(c) for c, sc in list_subcols.items()])\
    .show()

    +---------+-----------------+
    |pcxreport|crosslinediscount|
    +---------+-----------------+
    |       ab|              c e|
    +---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: in a list i have many data frame how should i merge all data frame in one data frame. length of list is not fixed...................thanks is advance